# Can we use a closure within a closure in javascript?

Tags: javascript

If I write something like below

```
function sum(x){
   return function(y){
       return function(z){
             return x + y + z;
}
}
}
```

and call it like  sum(2)(3)(4) // output is 8

can we call the above function, an example of closure within a closure ???

Comment: Yes, obviously you can, as you've posted an example of it.

Comment: Why to downvote...this term is not clear so I am asking to cummunity.

Comment: Of course, you can. This is called **currying** in functional programming. It is useful to reduce function arity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is an example of closure within a closure.